# How to increment timestamp using number of seconds from another column in Presto?

Tags: timestamp, increment, presto

I have two columns in my Presto table (call it table_a): `time_clmn` and `delta_clmn`. Their respective data type are: timestamp and bigint. I would like to increment `time_clmn` by `delta_clmn` but getting back error:

```
select time_clmn + interval cast(delta_clmn as varchar) second as new_field
from table_a
```

Here is error message:

```
SQL Error [1]: Query failed (#20190820_164600_02306_kzuv6): line 2:20: mismatched input 'cast'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AT', '[', '||', <expression>
```

Is there work around?

Sorry I cannot find online demo of Presto to illustrate my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`date_add`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_add) function like this:

```
SELECT date_add('SECOND', delta_clmn, time_clmn)
FROM (VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-08-20 18:50', 42)) t(time_clmn, delta_clmn);
```

```
          _col0
-------------------------
 2019-08-20 18:50:42.000
(1 row)
```